# Data-Source in Bootstrap Typeahead not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty straight forward question here. I have this code right here.

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/typeahead_data_countries.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
       source: country_array
   })
});

</script>
```

Where typeahead_data_countries is: var country_array = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria",...);

The variable gets loaded properly, but the whole typeahead is not working. If I do however:

```
<input type="text" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Afghanistan", "Albania"]'/>
```

it works, but I don't want that...

Comment: Actualy it looks fine So your problem is something simple that you cannot notice. And for sure it is something in code not included here. First check JS console for errors Second check it

Answer (score 3):

I think problem in your example based on mixing two different way to initializing typahead (js and data-*). This exapmle was work for me:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
          $('.typeahead').typeahead({
             items:4,
             source: ['Aaaa', 'Abbb', 'Accc']
          });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, the only way I got this working is by removing the $(function(){ }): that surrounds everything else. Hence:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        items:4,
        source: ['Aaaa', 'Abbb', 'Accc']
    });

</script>
```